# Issue in running apache2 from chroot environment

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, chroot

I am trying to run the apache2 server from chroot environment following this link http://archive09.linux.com/feature/36331. The only difference is that I started the `/usr/sbin/apache2` after getting into the chroot by issuing the command `sudo chroot chtest/` (where chtest is my chroot directory) and then after `/usr/sbin/apache2`. I got the error:
`apache2: bad user name www-data`
However I copied the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` file into my chroot file system. I am not able to figure out why the www-data user is not recognized within the chroot environment.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is /etc/nsswitch.conf in your chroot?

Comment: No, I have not copied /etc/nsswitch.conf in my chroot. Do I need to copy it?

Comment: Yes that is why you are getting the error. This is listed as one of the steps in the document you linked. You need to follow all the steps - also check the files you create have the right permissions.

Comment: I copied that but still the same issue.